# Google.maps.api, JavaScript; Moving vertex of many polygons at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

I have a bunch of polygons (`google.maps.Polygon`) that i have imported to a map. They lay edge to edge and share vertexes so there is no "empty area in between" (you can imagine country-borders, or zip-code-areas), so it's kind of like a grid.

Now, I want my users to be able to edit this grid:
When one movies a vertex of a polygon from position (x1, y1) to (x2, y2), then all other vertexes (of the other polygons) on that same location (x1, y1) should move to the new location (x2, y2).

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

This is what I have tried:
I can make the polygon `editable: true`, which will allow the user to drag the vertexes, but not all polygons vertexes will follow.

I tried to ad a `"set_at"` listener for the polygons that, once a vertex has been moved, loops throw the other polygons and check if they have a vertex with the same coordinates as the start, and if so, move that coordinate to the new location. Problem is that I don't know how to get the start-coordinate of the moved coordinate, only the end-coordinate.

Is there a better way to solv this problem than using polygons, like a grid?

Huge thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to move all other coordinates. Why don't you make editable polygon.Let the user himself add/edit the polygon on google map. I am sharing my code, in which i am creating bunch of polygons and user is able to edit it as well

```
<pre> 
var COLORS = [["red", "#ff0000"], ["orange", "#ff8800"], ["green","#008000"], ["blue", "#000080"], ["purple", "#800080"]];
var options         = {};
var lineCounter_    = 0;
var shapeCounter_   = 0;
var markerCounter_  = 0;
var colorIndex_     = 0;
var featureTable_;
var map;

//Active selective controller
function select(buttonId) 
{
  document.getElementById("hand_b").className="unselected";
  document.getElementById("shape_b").className="unselected";
  //document.getElementById("line_b").className="unselected";
  //document.getElementById("placemark_b").className="unselected";
  document.getElementById(buttonId).className="selected";
}
//Active tab after editing completion
function stopEditing() 
{
  select("hand_b");
}

function getColor(named) 
{
  return COLORS[(colorIndex_++) % COLORS.length][named ? 0 : 1];
}

function getIcon(color) 
{
  var icon          = new GIcon();
  icon.image        = "http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/" + color + ".png";
  icon.iconSize     = new GSize(32, 32);
  icon.iconAnchor   = new GPoint(15, 32);
  return icon;
}

function startShape() 
{
  select("shape_b");
  var color         = getColor(false);
  var polygon       = new GPolygon([], color, 2, 0.7, color, 0.2);
  startDrawing(polygon, "Shape " + (++shapeCounter_), function() 
  {
    var cell        = this;
    var area        = polygon.getArea();
    cell.innerHTML  = (Math.round(area / 10000) / 100) + "km<sup>2</sup>";
  }, color);
}



function addFeatureEntry(name, color) 
{
  currentRow_   = document.createElement("tr");
  var colorCell = document.createElement("td");
  currentRow_.appendChild(colorCell);
  colorCell.style.backgroundColor   = color;
  colorCell.style.width             = "1em";
  var nameCell                      = document.createElement("td");
  currentRow_.appendChild(nameCell);
  nameCell.innerHTML                = name;
  var descriptionCell               = document.createElement("td");
  currentRow_.appendChild(descriptionCell);
  featureTable_.appendChild(currentRow_);
  return {desc: descriptionCell, color: colorCell};
}

function startDrawing(poly, name, onUpdate, color) 
{
  map.addOverlay(poly);
  poly.enableDrawing(options);
  poly.enableEditing({onEvent: "mouseover"});
  poly.disableEditing({onEvent: "mouseout"});
  GEvent.addListener(poly, "endline", function() 
  { 
                                        select("hand_b");
                                        //SANI: getting all vertix of polygon
                                        var str = '{"zones":['; 
                                        for (var i = 0, I = poly.getVertexCount(); i < I; ++i) 
                                              {
                                                  var xy = poly.getVertex(i);
                                                  str += '{"lat":"'+xy.lat() + '", "long":"' + xy.lng() + '"}';

                                                  if(i != Number(I-1))
                                                  str += ',';

                                              }

                                        str += ']}'; 

                                        //SANI: getting polygon name
                                        var n = prompt("Enter polygon name:", "");

                                        frmFeilds = "latlng="+str+"&name="+n;
                                        //SANI: storing lat,long and name into database
                                        $(document).ready(
                                                            function()
                                                            { 

                                                                $.ajax({
                                                                            url: 'save_polygon.php',
                                                                            type:'POST',
                                                                            data:'action=yes&'+frmFeilds,
                                                                            success: function(sani)
                                                                            {   
                                                                                featureTable_.innerHTML = sani;
                                                                            }
                                                                        });

                                                            }
                                                         ); 

    //select("hand_b"); 
   // var cells = addFeatureEntry(name, color);
    GEvent.bind(poly, "lineupdated", cells.desc, onUpdate);
    GEvent.addListener(poly, "click", function(latlng, index) 
    {
      if (typeof index == "number") 
      {
        poly.deleteVertex(index);
      } else {
                var newColor = getColor(false);
                cells.color.style.backgroundColor = newColor
                poly.setStrokeStyle({color: newColor, weight: 4});
             }
    });
  });
}



function initialize() 
{
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
  {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(25.18622, 55.23866), 11);
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.clearOverlays();
    featureTable_ = document.getElementById("featuretbody");
    select("hand_b");

    /* S@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@NI */

  <?php
        $zoneQry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tbl_zones where zon_status = '1'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($zoneQry) > 0)
        {
            while($zoneRec = mysql_fetch_assoc($zoneQry))
            {

                $json   = (string)$zoneRec['zon_vertix'];
                $obj    = json_decode($json, true);
     ?>
                var polygon<?php echo $zoneRec['zon_id']; ?> = new GPolygon([
                                                                                <?php
                                                                                    foreach($obj['zones'] as $zones)
                                                                                    {
                                                                                ?>
                                                                                new GLatLng(<?php echo $zones['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $zones['long']; ?>),
                                                                                <?php } ?>

                                                                           ], "#f06ca8", 2, 1, "#89cff1", 0.5);
               drawShapBySani(polygon<?php echo $zoneRec['zon_id']; ?>);
               updatezones(<?php echo $zoneRec['zon_id']; ?>, polygon<?php echo $zoneRec['zon_id']; ?>);
    <?php               
            }
        }
    ?>



      /* S@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@NI */
  }
}
/* S@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  SANI: Update all Zones  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@NI */
function updatezones(zonid, zoneObj)
{
    //Update zones on click
        $("#updatezone").click(function() {
                                                //alert(zonid+', '+zoneObj);
                                                var str = '{"zones":['; 
                                                for(var i = 0, I = zoneObj.getVertexCount(); i < I; ++i) 
                                                {
                                                          var xy = zoneObj.getVertex(i);
                                                          str += '{"lat":"'+xy.lat() + '", "long":"' + xy.lng() + '"}';

                                                          if(i != Number(I-1))
                                                          str += ',';

                                                }

                                                str += ']}'; 


                                                    //SANI: getting polygon name


                                                    frmFeilds = "latlng="+str+"&id="+zonid;
                                                    //SANI: storing lat,long and name into database
                                                    $(document).ready(
                                                                        function()
                                                                        { 

                                                                            $.ajax({
                                                                                        url: 'save_polygon.php',
                                                                                        type:'POST',
                                                                                        data:'action=yes&'+frmFeilds,
                                                                                        success: function(sani)
                                                                                        {   
                                                                                            featureTable_.innerHTML = sani;
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    });

                                                                        }
                                                                     ); 
                                          });
}
/* S@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  SANI: Draw Editable Shap  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@NI */
function drawShapBySani(polygon)
{
    map.addOverlay(polygon);
    startDrawing(polygon, 'sani', function() {
                                                var cell        = this;
                                                var area        = polygon.getArea();
                                                cell.innerHTML  = (Math.round(area / 10000) / 100) + "km<sup>2</sup>";
                                             }, '#ff0000');
    select("hand_b"); 
    polygon.disableEditing();
}
</pre>
```

Hope it'll work for you.

Thanks